# Using Derivatives to Prove Slant Asymptotes

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, derivatives, asymptotics

Is it possible to prove a slant asymptote using the limit of the derivative as it approaches infinity? If so, does the following work I provided count as proof for finding the equation instead of using the proper method of polynomial division to prove the asymptote? I'm not sure since this method was never mentioned in my Calculus course, but appears to work as a proof.

$$\text{Let $C$ be an arbitrary constant.}$$
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\pm\infty}f'(x)=C$$

$$\text{Let $a$ be the $x$-value at which the tangent line was created.}$$
$$y=\lim_{a\rightarrow\pm\infty}\left[f'(a)(x-a)+f(a)\right]$$

I used the following function $f(x)$ to test if it worked:
$$f(x)=\frac{-3x^3+2x}{2x^2}+4$$
$$\text{Slope of tangent line:}$$
$$m=\lim_{x\rightarrow\pm\infty}f'(x)=-\frac{3}{2}$$
$$\text{Final equation for asymptote:}$$
$$y=\lim_{a\rightarrow\pm\infty}\left[-\frac{3}{2}(x-a)+\left(\frac{-3a^3+2a}{2a^2}+4\right)\right]$$
$$y=-\frac{3}{2}x+4$$

Comment: Faster is the division (or long division)

Comment: This depends on the definition of "asymptote" used. Older texts (mostly before 1950s I think) require both the function and its derivative to approach that of the asymptote (a line), whereas the usual definition in texts since then (especially precalculus and elementary calculus texts) don't require anything about the derivative of the function (even its existence). See [Can we determine an oblique asymptote of a function by the limit of $f'(x)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2487877/13130) *AND* [Formula for Oblique Asymptotes](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4279358/13130)

Comment: In case my comment to the 2nd MSE question I referenced above is overlooked, for a very thorough discussion of the definition one finds in older texts (especially from the 1800s, such as those by [Edwards & Todhunter & Williamson](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/3959/745)), see Haghdad S. Memauri and Herman Lee Windham, [*On asymptotes of the graphs of algebraic functions*](https://www.kappamuepsilon.org/Pentagon/Vol_52_Num_2_Spring_1993.pdf), **The Pentagon** 52 #2 (Spring 1993), 39-50.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense! I wanted to try this out to understand if such an approach could help determine slant asymptotes.